What is the discrete Fourier transform of a square of a function?
I am trying to figure out the discrete fourier transform of a squared function (specifically the squared error function between targets $y$ and predictions $\hat{y}$ ).
$$
\begin{align}
    \tilde{E}&=DFT(E)=DFT\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i})^2\right) \\
    &= \sum_{i} DFT((y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i})^2) \\
    &= \sum_{i} DFT(y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i}) DFT(y_{i}-\hat{y}_{i})\\
    &= \sum_{i} (DFT(y_{i})-DFT(\hat{y}_{i})) (DFT(y_{i})-\mathcal{F}(\hat{y}_{i}))\\
    &= \sum_{i} (\tilde{Y}_{i}-\hat{\tilde{Y}}_{i})^2\\
    &= \sum_{i} (\tilde{Y}_{i}-\hat{\tilde{Y}}_{i})^2\\
\end{align}
$$
I am pretty sure that the 3rd line in the above derivation is wrong, I think the correct step should use Parseval's theorem or the Convolution theorem, but I'm not really sure how to apply them since Parseval's theorem has a complex conjugate in the convolution (plus I'm not sure whether it applies to non-periodic functions defined on a finite time-interval) and the Convolution theorem has one function offset by some time $\tau$.
